# Adobe Air Mobile + Camera - Retaining image

Tags: apache-flex, air, camera

I have a page that displays data about an object. At the top of the page is room for an icon, showing a picture of that object. Tapping this icon brings up a new page that allows the user to take a new picture, and save it as a temporary new picture for the object (not put in database, but should persist for the session)

Initial page:

```
private var source:Object = new Object();

protected function onInitialize():void {
   source = navigator.poppedViewReturnedObject;
}
```

When setting source for the image later...

```
if (source != null) {
   pic.source = source.object;
}
else {
   pic.source = "no_picture_available_image.png";
}
```

2nd Page (User can take picture, and view new picture):

```
[Bindable]
private var imageSource:Object = null;

<s:Image id="pic" width="90%" height="75%" horizontalCenter="0" source="{imageSource}" />
```

After taking picture...

```
protected function mediaPromiseLoaded(evt:Event):void {
   var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = evt.target as LoaderInfo;
   imageSource = loaderInfo.loader;
}
```

This does show the picture just taken correctly on this page.

To get back to old page, i use navigator.popView, and use:

```
override public function createReturnObject():Object {
   return imageSource;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The imageSource isn't null when it is read from navigator.poppedViewReturnedObject, but no image is shown.

Does the LoaderInfo not persist after popping the view? Are the camera pics not automatically saved? I can't find answers to any of these questions, and I can't debug using the phone in my current environment.

Comment: What's the datatype of `poppedViewReturnedObject`?

Comment: Object. Contains a context, and the object returned from createReturnObject

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a bit, don't return `LoaderInfo.loader` as the `poppedViewReturnedObject`. If I remember correctly, a `DisplayObject` can only be set as the source of **one** `Image`. Instead, return `LoaderInfo.loader.content.bitmapData`. That `BitmapData` should be the raw data used to display the image. This data can be used repeatedly to create images and can be set as the source of an `Image`.

Comment: still not working - content doesn't have a bitmapdata property, but I created a bitmap manually from the content's width, height, and the bitmapdata's draw on loader.content. No result

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be in my first page's image declaration - I didn't set a width. Seemingly, the object being displayed couldn't handle not having a specified width.

Note that passing back the loader did work fine.